# При записи/чтении в/из EEPROM микроконтроллер как-будто пропускает шаги/повторяет цикл

Tags: arduino

Программирую микроконтроллер AMGEGA328P. Проблема начинается в функции writeNewSensorSettings(). Кратное описание - есть массив ячеек EEPROM, я прохожусь по нему начиная с 0 до 1000 по 3 шт. Так как я записываю в ячейку структуру, имеющую в себе 3 значения типа byte. Функция начинает с 0 , проверяет ячейку на пустоту сравнивая значения из нее с 255 (пусты ячейки по дефолту забиты как 255), затем, если ячейка пуста и если i=0 ставит id = 1 (т.к это первый элемент), а если i!=0, то просто смотрит на id на 3 элемента назад и делает id+1, заполняет структура инфой и пишет в EEPROM. Так вот, тут и начинается магия - если я пишу допустим 3 структуры, моя функция может написать мне и 5 и 6 структур (как-будто одна из них дублируется несколько раз или каждая из них дублируется по 2 раза) (что я точно заметил, так это то, что 0-й элемент может быть пустым, но функция isitFreeCell() - скажет что он полный (что на самом деле неверно), но при этом он все-же заполнится новой информацией и таким образом функция заполнит по 2-3 ячейки перед тем как закончится первая итерация цикла). **Но** как только я пытаюсь отследить ошибку при помощи Serial - ошибка перестает иметь места и все записывается корректно (я вставляю ооочень много Serial.print на каждом "повороте". Думал что проблема в скорости записи/чтения из eeprom. Натыкал везде delay, не помогло.

```
// ЭТО СКЕТЧ ПРИЁМНИКА (БАЗА)!!!
//--------------------- НАСТРОЙКИ ----------------------
#define CH_NUM 0x60   // номер канала, должен совпадать с передатчиком (датчик)

// УРОВЕНЬ МОЩНОСТИ ПЕРЕДАТЧИКА
// На выбор RF24_PA_MIN, RF24_PA_LOW, RF24_PA_HIGH, RF24_PA_MAX
#define SIG_POWER RF24_PA_MAX

// СКОРОСТЬ ОБМЕНА
// На выбор RF24_2MBPS, RF24_1MBPS, RF24_250KBPS
// должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
// при самой низкой скорости имеем самую высокую чувствительность и дальность!!
// ВНИМАНИЕ!!! enableAckPayload (основная функция обмена данными) НЕ РАБОТАЕТ НА СКОРОСТИ 250 kbps!
#define SIG_SPEED RF24_1MBPS
//--------------------- НАСТРОЙКИ ----------------------

//--------------------- БИБЛИОТЕКИ ---------------------
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10); // "создать" модуль на пинах 9 и 10
//--------------------- БИБЛИОТЕКИ ---------------------

//--------------------- ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ----------------------
byte address[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node", "5Node", "6Node"}; //возможные номера труб
byte Data[3];         // массив принятых данных
byte callbackData[2]; //массив отправляемых данных
byte pipeNo; //Байтовая переменная хранения номера трубы для отправки
struct Sensor { //Переменная типа struct для хранения данных о датчике
  byte id;
  byte type;
  byte data;
};
//--------------------- ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ ----------------------

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //открываем порт для связи с ПК
  radioSetup();
  for(int i =0; i<90; i++){
    clearSensorById(i);
    delay(200);
   Serial.print("Info "); Serial.println(eeprom_read_byte(i));
   delay(5);
  }
 
}

void loop() {
      while( radio.available(&pipeNo)){    // слушаем эфир со всех труб
        radio.read( &Data, sizeof(Data) );         // чиатем входящий сигнал
        if (Data[0] == 0){
          Sensor newSensor;
          writeNewSensorSettings(Data[1],Data[2],newSensor);
          callbackData[0]=newSensor.id;
          callbackData[1]=newSensor.type;
          radio.writeAckPayload(pipeNo, &callbackData, sizeof(callbackData));
//        Serial.print("Recieved: ID "); Serial.println(Data[0]);
//        Serial.print("Recieved: TYPE "); Serial.println(Data[1]);
//        Serial.print("Recieved: DATA "); Serial.println(Data[2]) ;
          }
        Serial.print("Recieved: ID "); Serial.println(Data[0]);
        Serial.print("Recieved: TYPE "); Serial.println(Data[1]);
        Serial.print("Recieved: DATA "); Serial.println(Data[2]);
     }
}

void radioSetup() {         // настройка радио модуля
  radio.begin();               // активировать модуль
  radio.setAutoAck(1);         // режим подтверждения приёма, 1 вкл 0 выкл
  radio.setRetries(0, 15);     // (время между попыткой достучаться, число попыток)
  radio.enableAckPayload();    // разрешить отсылку данных в ответ на входящий сигнал
  radio.setPayloadSize(32);    // размер пакета, байт
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address[0]);   // хотим слушать трубу 0
  radio.setChannel(CH_NUM);               // выбираем канал
  radio.setPALevel(SIG_POWER);            // уровень мощности передатчика
  radio.setDataRate(SIG_SPEED);           // скорость обмена
  // должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
  // при самой низкой скорости имеем самую высокую чувствительность и дальность!!

  radio.powerUp();         // начать работу
  radio.startListening();  // начинаем слушать эфир, мы приёмный модуль
}

bool isItFreeCell(int num) {
  byte cash = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)num);
  delay(15);
  if (cash == 255) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

void clearSensorById(int id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i= i + 3) 
  {
    if (eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i) == id) 
    {
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i, 255);
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i + 1, 255);
      delay(10);
      eeprom_write_byte((byte*)i + 2, 255);
      delay(10);
      break;
    }
  }
}

void writeNewSensorSettings(byte type, byte data, Sensor& CallbackData) {
  Sensor mySensor;
  mySensor.type = type;
  mySensor.data = data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 3) {
    if (isItFreeCell(i) == true) {
      if (i==0){
         mySensor.id=1;
        }else {
         mySensor.id = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i-3)+1; //Чтение из eeprom 
          }
      eeprom_write_block((void*)&mySensor, (int*)i, sizeof(mySensor));
      eeprom_read_block((void*)&CallbackData, (int*)i, sizeof(CallbackData)); 
      break;
    }
  }
}

void readSensorSettingsById(Sensor& mySensor, int id){
    for (int i =0;i<1000;i= i+3){
       if (eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i) == id) {
        eeprom_read_block((void*)&mySensor, (int*)i, sizeof(mySensor));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Если кому-то поможет. 1-я ссылка - вывожу первые 15 элементов EEPROM 
https://ibb.co/xgsHj1x

2- я ссылка - в цикле пытаюсь записать 3 стукруты в EEPROM и результат - аж 5 структур записались в EEPROM вместо 3-х. (цифра до цифры 20 в цикле я ставил естественно 3, а 20 - для того, чтобы показать немного больше ячеек EEPROM)
https://ibb.co/yf6MTvL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, но непонятно почему потоки в arduino работают именно так. Был добавлен delay(500); иначе условие не дожидалось окончания функции isItFreeCell(i) и приходила сразу к записи

```
void writeNewSensorSettings(byte type, byte data, Sensor& CallbackData) {
  Sensor mySensor;
  mySensor.type = type;
  mySensor.data = data;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 3) {
//    Serial.print("i= "); Serial.println(i) ;
    if (isItFreeCell(i) == true) {
      delay(500);
      if (i==0){
         mySensor.id=1;
        }else {
         mySensor.id = eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i-3)+1; //Чтение из eeprom 
          }
//      Serial.print("Старый id = "); Serial.println(mySensor.id);
//        Serial.print("Новый id = "); Serial.println(eeprom_read_byte((uint8_t*)i-3)) ;
      eeprom_write_block((void*)&mySensor, (int*)i, sizeof(mySensor));
      eeprom_read_block((void*)&CallbackData, (int*)i, sizeof(CallbackData)); 
      break;
    }
  }
}
```